# How to format a CSV file using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, format

Currently I am able to query a MYSQL database using PHP and my data is imported into a CSV with no problems. However, I need to take the column data on the top row, and put it in rows on the left side instead and i need my data under each column to correlate with the correct row. So basically, I need PHP to transpose data in excel exactly like the transpose tool in excel.

**Here is my current code:**

```
ExportMysqlToCsv($tablename);

function exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$filename = 'Results.csv')
{
    $csv_terminated = "\n";
    $csv_separator = ",";
    $csv_enclosed = '"';
    $csv_escaped = "\\";
    $sql_query = "select * from $tablename where id=2";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $fields_cnt = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $schema_insert = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
    {
        $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
            stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
        $schema_insert .= $l;
        $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
    } // end for

    $out = trim(substr($schema_insert, 0, -1));
    $out .= $csv_terminated;

    // Format the data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $fields_cnt; $j++)
        {
            if ($row[$j] == '0' || $row[$j] != '')
            {

                if ($csv_enclosed == '')
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $row[$j];
                } else
                {
                    $schema_insert .= $csv_enclosed . 
                    str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed, $row[$j]) . $csv_enclosed;
                }
            } else
            {
                $schema_insert .= '';
            }

            if ($j < $fields_cnt - 1)
            {
                $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
            }
        } // end for

        $out .= $schema_insert;
        $out .= $csv_terminated;
    } // end while


    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));

 // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    echo $out;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: don't deal with the csv data. convert it back to a native data structure (e.g. array) and do the manipulations there. you'll save yourself a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: http://php.net/fputcsv http://php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: If this is not for practice, but for practical purposes, use the `select into outfile...` syntax in mysql.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this will simplify your code a lot:

```
function exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$filename = 'Results.csv')
{
    $sql_query = "select * from $tablename where id=2";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($first) {
            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
            $first = false;
        }
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    } // end while

    $size = ftell($f);
    rewind($f);

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: $size");

 // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    fpassthru($f);
    exit;
}
```

What you're after is a pivot operation; unfortunately, you can't do that without reading all rows into memory and then applying the transformation.

See [here](http://gonzalo123.com/2010/01/24/pivot-tables-in-php/) for some inspiration.

Comment: Finally some help! Thanks Jack!